# Make play store recommendations from other people disappear

Tags: google-play-store, gmail

For some reason my android phone and tablet still try to recommend things that my ex is rating highly.

I am not sure where it is getting the idea that i would care she was but is no longer my 1 friend on google+ and ive deleted her email from recent emails in gmail. Where else would i go to clear this from my life. Its been well over a year btw so not like its just taking time to clear out.

Comment: Do you still have her in your contacts / address book?

Comment: no did find out i was still in a "circle" of hers on google+ blocked her to remove it there, cleared the cache on the store rebooted the tablet ...still showing up

Comment: Well, I think you should give it a little more time to clear things up as you yourself said that you were still in her circle which may be the reason why your ex rated apps shows up ! But as now you have removed the user I think things will update after a short while !